# Flask url_for with no blueprint file

Tags: python, flask

I have stored all urls in one place to make it easier to find routes:

```
from main import app 
from main import views as main
from auth import views as auth

METHODS = ['GET', 'POST']

app.add_url_rule('/',
                 view_func=main.index,
                 methods=METHODS)

# Auth & Registration
app.add_url_rule('/login',
                 view_func=auth.login,
                methods=METHODS)

app.add_url_rule('/register',
                 view_func=auth.index,
                 methods=METHODS)

app.add_url_rule('/forgot_password',
                 view_func=auth.forgot_password,
                 methods=METHODS)
```

So the following works:

```
redirect(url_for('login'))
```

But what if I have same method in two different packages, can I do something like:

```
redirect(url_for('auth.index'))
redirect(url_for('main.index'))
```

Or I can only use blueprints for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the inputs to `add_url_rule` is the endpoint which is what you will pass to `url_for`. So if you look at the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.add_url_rule), you will see that the second (non-keyword) argument is the end point. By default it sets it to the name of the function that you pass as your `view_func`.

```
app.add_url_rule('/register', 'auth.index', view_func=auth.index, methods=METHODS)
```

You can also simply pass `view_func` as a positional argument

```
app.add_url_rule('/register', 'auth.index', auth.index, methods=METHODS)
```