# Calling a function on HTML page, not found

Tags: python, html, flask

I am writing a tool to record and monitor downtime on a range of equipment.

I have my file structure as below:
[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6b7Me.png)

Sites is just a subfolder containing individual HTMLS for where the equipment is located.

Currently, flask runs webapp.py which contains:

```
>from . import app
>#app = (__init__.app) 
>from . import views 
>from . import ReportingTool
```

views.py has all of my @app.route's in it, up until the [site].html files. From there, on the [site].html file I ask for input from the user. I haven't started writing code to record the user input in any meaningful way, just want to get the data to a python script and commit them to variables. To this end, in the html file I have

```
<body>
    <div class="menu">
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart\form-data" action="{{ url_for('downTime') }}">
            <fieldset class="datafieldset">
```

This then requests different data from the user in the form of multiple field sets as seen here: [fieldsets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqsK2.png)

as you see in the code snippet above I set the action to be url_for('downTime'), downTime is a function in my python file ReportingTool.py. this throws out an error, "werkzeug.routing.exceptions.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'downTime'. Did you mean 'supportguide' instead?" [traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WByjz.png)

Is there something I need to add or specify on the html document to enable this page (and the other [site].html pages to call functions from the ReportingTool.py file? the @app.route that calls the [site].html file is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4M3dL.png) and that is called with a redirected from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62IDZ.png) I've only got it setup like that becuase I wanted the name for the site to appear in the address bar.

Thanks in advance.

I am not sure on steps to fix as I am kind of throwing myself in the deep end to learn basic coding by creating an application for my workplace to replace an excel spreadsheet I created.

Comment: Does the downTime function exist? You shared an image of the @app.route you are trying to reach, but you blurred out the function name and the route. Do you have a function called downTime?

Comment: As stated above, downTime is defined in ReportingTool.py "@app.route('/reported', methods=['POST'])
def downTime():"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not reaching the `downTime` function in the `ReportingTool.py` file. I suggest trying [add_url_rule](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/flask.Flask.add_url_rule.html#flask-flask-add-url-rule) in your `views.py` by adding the `/reported` endpoint referencing the `downTime` function in ReportingTool.py. Something like this;

```
app.add_url_rule('/reported', 'ReportingTool.downTime', view_func=ReportingTool.downTime, methods=METHODS)
```

This answer is based on the responds for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842396/flask-url-for-with-no-blueprint-file). You are trying to reach a function in a different file from your main view file. Assuming you are calling the page with the form from a function in the `views.py` file.

Comment: Does /reported need to be the action on the form's element tags?

Answer (score 0):

Solved with info from Kakedis' input, and the links they provided.

I added:

```
app.add_url_rule('/reported', 'ReportingTool.downTime', view_func=ReportingTool.downTime, methods=METHODS)
```

to webbapp.py, then:

```
@app.route('/reported')
def downTime():
    try:
        DTref = request.form['refDT']
    except:
        DTref = "No Reference"
    print(DTref)
    print("reported")
    return(render_template("/UserRip.html"))
```

to ReportingTool.py

This now prints the above to console to confirm it's pulling the correct func and brings the user back to the starting page.